# Database of Google play store apps

Tags: json, database, nosql, google-play-services

I need a database that has information about all Google Play Store apps and games (including name, product ID, category), and can also be downloaded and updated all the time. Please help.

I tried in Google and Bing chat.
I expected to get a database with API that has information about all Google Play Store apps and games.